# How to set "Accept Ranges: byte" in Apache Coyote 1.1 tomcat server?

Tags: tomcat

I'm having a little issue with video files. Apparently, for mobile videos, server should support byte range. The following is response headers from my video request.

```
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Disposition filename=test.mp4
Expires Sat, 10 Sep 2011 21:02:51 +0000
Cache-Control   public, max-age=2592000
Last-Modified   Tue, 09 Aug 2011 22:42:45 +0000
Etag    dot:9aa53bc0-703e-4628-929f-15a874a8a172:1312929765000:14351674
Content-Type    video/mp4
Content-Length  14351674
Date    Thu, 11 Aug 2011 21:02:51 GMT
```

How do I add "Accept Ranges: byte" to my server configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the default servlet pushing out these files, or a custom one?  And what version of Tomcat are you on?

If it's default, this should be working as of Tomcat 6.0.19 ([reference](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45419)).

If not, you're looking at setting up an output filter to buffer the whole output and select the ranges for return to the client - if you're needing to go this route, I'd recommend setting up a different web service for handling the range-enabled video files.